# PyQt - issue with inheritance

Tags: python, qt, class, inheritance, pyqt

I'm having tough time with this weird issue. I put some QLineEdit widgets in my project and trying to select (highlight) all of their text with simply clicking on them. I had this working already but then I wanted to stretch this functionality to the other class of the same QLineEdit parent. I made this little interface:

```
class EditInterface(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(EditInterface, self).__init__(parent)
        self.focus = False
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        ret = QtGui.QLineEdit.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        if not self.focus:
            self.selectAll()
            self.focus=True
        else:
            self.deselect()
        return ret

    def focusInEvent(self,event):
        self.focus=True
        return QtGui.QLineEdit.focusInEvent(self,event)

    def focusOutEvent(self,event):
        self.focus=False
        return QtGui.QLineEdit.focusOutEvent(self,event)
```

Right now it's not working at all. If i simply do this:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    ret = QtGui.QLineEdit.mousePressEvent(self, event)
    self.selectAll()
    return ret
```

Then it's working fine, but I want it to enable other mouse activities rather than just selecting everything over and over again.
Problem seems to be with the self.focus variable but I'm not experienced in python and have no clue what's going on. Everything else is working well in my project so I'll skip posting it here.
Thanks in advance

**Edit: I found the problem**
It wasn't about inheritance at all but about events. focusInEvent is called before mousePressEvent is so it was impossible to ever call selectAll().

Comment: I don't see any `QWidget.focus` attribute anywhere in the [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html). Shouldn't it be [`setFocus()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setFocus) and [`clearFocus()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#clearFocus)?

Comment: I see now that the name of this variable is deceiving. It isn't bound with parent classes, I just use it to determine if my widget has focus at the moment so I know when to self.selectAll(). I know it's pretty old-fashioned solution to this problem but that's all i could think of. Edit: also note that this code was working well when it was within the child class that's inheriting from this interface so I expect it to be inheritance problem